# How to modify all output files to conceal passwords in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I'd like to conceal passwords from output files in Robot Framework.
In particular, I'm looking for a native possibility (not multiple commands):

- to run a robot framework test retrieving one or more passwords from a vault through a custom keyword
- and to remove in the output files (output.xml, log.html and report.html) all the strings equal to the password(s) retrieved.

I managed to do it for output.xml through --prerebotmodifier and a simple Python script I made, but the html files (log and report) are generated after the call to the Python script and so passwords are not concealed in there.

It's not possible to use --removekeywords since the password could be used somewhere else in the test and with DEBUG or TRACE it would be shown in the logs.

Another solution would be to run the Python script in a separate command (e.g. through `||`) but this is not what I'd like to achieve.

```sh
robot --prerebotmodifier lib/password_clean.py -L TRACE testConceal.robot
```

```
Test to get password
    ${password}=  get password  ${SOME_PARAMETERS}
    Log To Console  ${password}
```

The expected result would be not to see the value of `${password}` in output.xml, log.html and report.html with one Robot Framework native command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use --removekeywords (https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#removing-keywords)
e.g.

`--removekeywords get password`

You could use NAME:

`--removekeywords NAME:*password*`. Any keywords with 'password' in title get removed.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer. I already tried it, but it's not removing the variables containing the passwords (if the test is run with `-L TRACE` all variables values will be shown).

Comment: I know "Input Password" hides the password from the log. I guess you could make a custom Log that does the same. I am assuming you sometimes want the password logged and sometimes not. I am also guessing these passwords are not "test data" passwords that are not private.

Comment: I mean they ARE private :)

Comment: As far as I remember the ouput XML would still contain the information while the log.html would be ok.

Comment: Just to be sure I understood: when you say to create a custom Log, it means to overwrite the Log of Robot Framework by extending the JAR? https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extending-the-robot-framework-jar

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick win which would be to use `--listener` instead of `--prerebotmodifier`. Still working on it, though.